# Setup Codiad with Nginx Installation Error

Tags: nginx, ide, digital-ocean

I'm trying to setup Codiad with Nginx in my droplet, although I've set all permissions to Codiad files to my user, when I navigate to those files, Codiad keeps sending me "Installation Error" message, which is the following:

```
Installation Error

Please make sure the following exist and are writeable: 
[SYSTEM]/config.php - ERROR 
[SYSTEM]/workspace - ERROR 
[SYSTEM]/plugins - ERROR 
[SYSTEM]/themes - ERROR 
[SYSTEM]/data - ERROR
```

Here's my nginx configuration:

```
server { 
listen 8081; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied 
listen [::]:8081 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /var/www/html/codiad; 
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/ 
server_name domain;

location / { 
# First attempt to serve request as file, then 
# as directory, then fall back to index.html 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; 
}

error_page 404 /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html 
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html; 
location = /50x.html { 
root /var/www/html; 
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000 
location ~ \.php$ { 
try_files $uri =404; 
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; 
fastcgi_index index.php; 
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
include fastcgi_params; 
} 
}
```

Also, these are the currently set permissions:

```
ls -l /var/www/html/codiad/

total 124 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cae cae 370 Dec 2 05:01 AUTHORS.txt 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cae cae 11357 Dec 2 05:01 common.php 
drwxrwxr-x 16 cae cae 4096 Dec 2 05:01 components 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cae cae 1127 Dec 2 05:01 composer.json 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cae cae 1612 Dec 2 05:01 config.example.php 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cae cae 1612 Dec 2 05:02 config.php 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cae cae 1489 Dec 2 05:01 CONTRIBUTING.md 
drwxrwxr-x 2 cae cae 4096 Dec 2 05:01 data 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cae cae 1150 Dec 2 05:01 favicon.ico 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cae cae 17210 Dec 2 05:01 index.php 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cae cae 634 Dec 2 05:01 INSTALL.txt 
drwxrwxr-x 2 cae cae 4096 Dec 2 05:01 js 
drwxrwxr-x 2 cae cae 4096 Dec 2 05:01 languages 
drwxrwxr-x 2 cae cae 4096 Dec 2 05:01 lib 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cae cae 1133 Dec 2 05:01 LICENSE.txt 
drwxrwxr-x 2 cae cae 4096 Dec 2 05:01 plugins 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cae cae 672 Dec 2 05:01 README.md 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cae cae 24394 Dec 2 05:01 style_guide.php 
drwxrwxr-x 3 cae cae 4096 Dec 2 05:01 themes 
drwxrwxr-x 2 cae cae 4096 Dec 2 05:01 workspace
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your permissions are belonging to your user. You are going to have to change the ownership of the directory to `www-data`. Run the following:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./*
```